# Use sudoer to restart server in post-receive git hook

Tags: git, webserver, hook, git-post-receive

I have to restart my webserver every time I make a change to my .pm files so I am trying to set up a restart in the post-receive hook.

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/web git checkout -f
rap stop
sleep 5
rap start
```

When I restart manually, I have to go root and type rap stop/start. Right now I'm getting

```
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 3: rap: command not found 
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 5: rap: command not found
```

when I make a push. I think permission are blocking me and I need some help to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you need those commands used as root, you could, as in "[How to execute commands as root in git post-receive hook](https://superuser.com/a/745773/141)":

> - create a separate script containing only the commands to run as root.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo /full/path/to/rap stop
    sudo /full/path/to/rap start
```

> - in the post-receive script do:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/current/myapp/
    set -x
    echo "Checking out new files on production and restarting app"
    echo $USER
    git checkout -f
    sudo /home/admin/restart-myapp
```

> - And finally in the `visudo`:

```
    %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
    admin   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/admin/restart-myapp
```